# Join two tables and sum a certain column

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I want to get 0 if sum result is null using Linq to SQL and C#.

Can anyone please help with this query?

```
internal decimal GetItemPurchasedByDate(linqToSqlDataContext db, int itemId, DateTime firstDay, DateTime lastDay)
{
    var count = (from pl in db.tblPurchaseLines
                 join p in db.tblPurchases on pl.PurchaseId equals p.PurchaseId
                 where pl.ItemId == itemId && p.PurchaseDate >= firstDay && p.PurchaseDate < lastDay
                 select pl.Qty).Sum();

    return count;
}
```

Comment: The count is decimal?

Comment: @ggeorge yes it is decimal

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this code as I see it is working so far, please if anyone has any comment to modify or to optimize then share with me.

```
var list = from pl in db.tblPurchaseLines
                   join p in db.tblPurchases on pl.PurchaseId equals p.PurchaseId
                   where pl.ItemId == itemId && p.PurchaseDate >= firstDay && p.PurchaseDate < lastDay
                   select new PurchaseLine
                   {
                       qty = pl.Qty
                   };
        if (list == null || list.Count() == 0)
            return 0;

        return list.ToList().Sum(k => (decimal?)k.qty) ?? 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
internal decimal? GetItemPurchasedByDate(linqToSqlDataContext db, int itemId, DateTime firstDay, DateTime lastDay)
{
     decimal? count = null;
     count = (from pl in db.tblPurchaseLines
             join p in db.tblPurchases on pl.PurchaseId equals p.PurchaseId
             where pl.ItemId == itemId && p.PurchaseDate >= firstDay && p.PurchaseDate < lastDay
             select pl.Qty).Sum();
     
     if (!count.HasValue)
     {
         return 0;
     }

     return count;
}
```

Comment: Tried and didn't work, I got this error: The null value cannot be assigned to a member with type System.Decimal which is a non-nullable value type

Comment: Try to pass custom values to count to see if this method works as expected (it does work, because i have already tested it)

Comment: if there is a null then it throws exception. I did some work around, don't know if this is ok or not.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-coalescing-operator)

> The null-coalescing operator ?? returns the value of its left-hand operand if it isn't null; otherwise, it evaluates the right-hand operand and returns its result. The ?? operator doesn't evaluate its right-hand operand if the left-hand operand evaluates to non-null.

You can use `??` operator

```
var count = (from pl in db.tblPurchaseLines
                 join p in db.tblPurchases on pl.PurchaseId equals p.PurchaseId
                 where pl.ItemId == itemId && p.PurchaseDate >= firstDay && p.PurchaseDate < lastDay
                 select pl.Qty).Sum() ?? 0;
```